# How to create Dynamodb metrics in CDK typescript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am writing CDK to create my beautiful **Cloudwatch dashboard**. I figured out how to create a widget with **metrics using Lambda functions**. But I can't find a way to create **metrics for Dynamodb tables**.

Lambda function has its own metrics properties in it

```
lambdaFunction.metricErrors()
lambdaFunction.metricInvocations()
```

So, I could add lambdaFunction's metrics into my Cloudwatch dashboard
    const dashboard = new Dashboard(this, 'Dashboard', {
        dashboardName: 'ImageMetadataServiceCloudWatch'
    })

```
const widget = new cloudwatch.GraphWidget({
    title: title,
    left: [
        lambdaFunction.metricErrors(),
        lambdaFunction.metricInvocations()
    ],
    right: [
        lambdaFunction.metricDuration()
    ]
});

dashboard.add(widget);
```

But I have no clue of getting metrics for Dynamodb tables.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer. Good luck on future CDK users and welcome to the CDK world.

```
private metricForDynamoDBTable(table: dynamodb.Table, metricName: string, options: cloudwatch.MetricOptions = { }): cloudwatch.Metric {
    return new cloudwatch.Metric({
        metricName,
        namespace: 'AWS/DynamoDB',
        dimensions: {
          TableName: table.tableName
        },
        unit: cloudwatch.Unit.COUNT,
        label: metricName,
        ...options
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting here the python sample for dashboard creation, because there are not many source for CDK using Python on the internet:

```
    config_table_dashboard = aws_cloudwatch.Dashboard(self, "id", dashboard_name="provisionedthroughtput")
    dynamodb_metrics = []
    dynamodb_WCU_throughput = aws_cloudwatch.Metric(
        metric_name="ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits",
        namespace="AWS/DynamoDB",
        dimensions={"TableName": "table-name"},
        statistic="Average",
        unit=aws_cloudwatch.Unit.COUNT,
        period=core.Duration.minutes(amount=5))
    dynamodb_metrics.append(dynamodb_WCU_throughput)
    config_table_dashboard.add_widgets(aws_cloudwatch.GraphWidget(title="Dynamodb table provision", left=dynamodb_metrics))
```